# Navigation Controller & TableView: NavBar Hidden after hidden = true one time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView embedded in a NavigationController. The cells each link out to a larger information ViewController. For UI purposes, I hide the Navigation Bar on the TableView and show it in the InfoViewController.

The problem I am experiencing is this: upon booting the app, the NavBar is successfully hidden on the TableView. The first time I tap into a cell and open an InfoViewController, the NavBar comes back as expected. I back out of that VC and into the TableView. Again, the NavBar is hidden, as expected. If I tap into another cell, the NavBar is not displayed as expected. NOTE: This happens even when I remove any code to hide the Navigation Bar.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

TableViewController (in ViewDidLoad()):

`self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`

InfoViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Why would it work the first time, but not the second. Any help is appreciated!

For clarification:

App opens to TableView:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8MeF.png)

I click into the TableViewCell to Segue to InfoViewController:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu4vc.png)

I hit "Back" to go back to TableViewController. NavBar is still hidden. I click on the same cell:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4zb2.png)

EDITED: Messed up the TableViewController Code. Put `= false` instead of `= true`.

Also, I have one more thought, please someone check this for me. The TableViewController is inside a UIContainerView. It is almost as if when I hit "Back" I am exiting the NavigationController flow and I cannot get back in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code its working fine for hiding `navigationBar`

**TableViewController**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
}
```

**InfoViewController**

```
class InfoViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple hide navigationbar again when the view controller is appear again,

do below code in tableViewController:

`override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }`